# during dual boot of windows and ubuntu windows does not load

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows, laptop, uefi

on windows 8 preinstalled laptop(uefi) i tried to dual boot it with ubuntu 13.10 64 bit after installation grub did not appear. then i installed easyBCD on windows 8 then i tried to dual boot ubuntu with windows it didnot work. then accidentally i changed the boot location from c drive to \boot then none of the os run properly. i can easyly format my computer and load ubuntu into it but i have to save the costly windows 8 original version.please reply asap!!!

Comment: Do you have Windows & Ubuntu installer CDs? You should check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two relatively easy solutions to this problem:

- Create a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (download links for both are on that page). You should then be able to boot to rEFInd, and from there into either Windows or Linux. If this works, you can install the rEFInd Debian package in Linux and it should all work normally.
- Run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a live CD. This will re-install GRUB, with any luck in a working configuration vs. the non-working configuration you got when you installed Ubuntu.

In both cases, it's best if you [disable Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) before trying. Although Ubuntu officially supports Secure Boot, there are a lot of problems with it. Also, rEFInd works with Secure Boot only if you [jump through extra hoops.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html)

If neither of these solutions works, post back with the URL that Boot Repair provides. That will give us a better idea of how your system is currently set up.